# Groovy cannot be enabled for project its library isn't configured

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I'm following some tutorial to explore creating IntelliJ Platform Plugin. The interface as below

[image]

Upon clicking the `Groovy` checkbox, and click next, an error as below appear.

[image]

Clearly it needs some library. Where could I get the library? (I click `Create...`, it open the current folder. I don't know what to select from there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download library  from official site: http://groovy-lang.org/download.html and them select it after pressing "Create..."